# Environment variables - Spring, Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, cas

I couldn't setup database connection using environment properties.

Application is built with Spring and run in the Tomcat container (7.0.52).

XML file setup:

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://${CONF_MYSQL_HOST}:${CONF_MYSQL_PORT}/${CONF_MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      p:user="${CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN}"
      p:password="#${CONF_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      p:minPoolSize="6"
      p:maxPoolSize="18" />

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="casProperties"
                              system-properties-mode="FALLBACK"/>
```

When I run

```
echo $CONF_MYSQL_HOST
```

variable value is printed properly.

I also tried to pass values through setenv.sh placed in CATALINA_HOME/bin/':

```
export CONF_MYSQL_HOST=$CONF_MYSQL_HOST
export CONF_MYSQL_PORT=$CONF_MYSQL_PORT
export CONF_MYSQL_DATABASE=$CONF_MYSQL_DATABASE
export CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN=$CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN
export CONF_MYSQL_PASSWORD=$CONF_MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

but nothing has changed.

In the log file I see only:

```
jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://:/
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do JavaConfig like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  private Environment env;

  @Autowired
  public DatabaseConfig(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String jdbcUrl = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", env.getProperty("CONF_MYSQL_HOST"),
              env.getProperty("CONF_MYSQL_PORT"), env.getProperty("CONF_MYSQL_DATABASE"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("CONF_MYSQL_PASSWORD"));
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(6);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(18);

    return dataSource;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I would add this in a comment but I don't have the necessary reputation points yet.
>
> If you start your tomcat using a command line interface, your environment variables should be resolved by using a special Spring expression variable to reference them.
>
> > Did you try replacing ${CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN} with the corresponding Spring Expression language expression #{ systemEnvironment['CONF_MYSQL_LOGIN'] } for each of your variables.

Comment: Changing to `systemEnvironment` doesn't help. `systemProperties` also checked.